# How to update value in angular ui typeahead directive if no matching option is found

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui-typeahead

I've an array of objects containing title and salary which is used in typeahead directive.

I display department name and get entire object as value.

If none of the options match, I want user entered string to be converted to object still. Is there any way to update that?

Comment: post what have you have done so far, you can use [plunker](https://plnkr.co/) to create a code example for your question

Answer (score 0):

This answer is pretty late, but I would just use `ng-blur` (to trap the end of the users input) along with a variable bound to `typeahead-no-results`.  Then test if the variable is true in the method bound to `ng-blur`, and, if so, make an object out of the String supplied by the user and push it to your data source.   Simple example [found here](https://plnkr.co/edit/m8tSY4FCJWKrsw5iPcel?p=preview).